# Fix unrecognised Flash drive - no file system on the usb

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, filesystem

I installed Ubuntu on my PC from a flash drive and then deleted the iso image from the drive (which was obviously not the right way to do it). Now the drive appears to have no file system on it and when plugged to my machine, it is not recognized as a USB.

Here is output from my /var/log/syslog after plugging in the device:

```
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC kernel: [  672.067136] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC kernel: [  672.209476] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC kernel: [  672.209482] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC kernel: [  672.209486] usb 1-3: Product: Mass Storage Device
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC kernel: [  672.209490] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC kernel: [  672.210264] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC kernel: [  672.211663] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Aug  6 18:50:17 janPC mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Aug  6 18:50:18 janPC kernel: [  673.220014] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Aug  6 18:50:18 janPC kernel: [  673.220615] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Aug  6 18:50:18 janPC kernel: [  673.221571] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

and here is output of lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1    7:1    0  86,9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  14,1G  0 part 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 917,4G  0 part 
loop6    7:6    0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop4    7:4    0  86,9M  1 loop /snap/core/4830
loop2    7:2    0 162,9M  1 loop /snap/spotify/16
loop0    7:0    0 162,6M  1 loop /snap/spotify/6
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0   980M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  20,4G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0    93G  0 part 
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda6   8:6    0   4,7G  0 part /home
loop3    7:3    0 162,1M  1 loop /snap/spotify/13
```

From the syslog I would guess, that the device is given name sdc, but there is no info about partitions. I tried the following to mount the device:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sg2 /media/flash
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc /media/flash
```

but got something like 'sg2 is not a block device' and 'no medium found on sdc'. How can I fix my flash drive? I also tried testdisk, which did not recognize the device at all. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated as I am new to linux.